# How to make $\lim_{x \to 0} (1-2x)^{1/x}$ into $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ form for L'Hospital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to figure out how to make $\lim_{x \to 0} (1-2x)^{1/x}$ into $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ form for L'Hospital's Rule.

Using Desmos.com I have found that $(1-2x)^{1/x} \neq 1-2^{1/x}x^{1/x}$ and I'm not sure why that is either. That is the only thing I can think of to change the function's form.

Comment: Take $\log$ both side

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493771/lhospitals-rule-for-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-an-bn-frac1n?rq=1

Comment: It should be noted that the question @LuminousNutria marked as a dupe target is not an *exact* duplicate.  However, I agree that it is, abstractly, a good duplicate target.  The technique used there is identical: take a logarithm, work out the limit using L'H, then exponentiate.

Answer (score 5):

*A suggestion*:

Calculate the limit of the logarithm first:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(1-2x\right)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-2x)}x.$$

If you find the limit $\ell$ for the log, the limit of the  expression is $\mathrm e^{\ell}$.

Comment: If I differentiate both sides I can get $\frac{-2}{1-2x}$ from this, which, when I replace $x$ with zero, becomes $-2$, but Symbolab.com says the answer is $\frac{1}{e^2}$. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: $-2 $ is the limit of the log. Hence the limit of the expression is …

Comment: I wouldn't be able  to figure that out from your hints Bernard. At least tell me a term I can look up.

Comment: $(1-2x)^{1/x}=\mathrm e^{\frac 1x\ln(1-2x)}$ since the exponential  fiunction is the inverse function of the natural logarithm..

Comment: Oh! I see! I get it now $\lim_{x \to 0} (1-2x)^{1/x} = e^{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1-2x)}{x}}$ The exponent of $e$ becomes $-2$.

Comment: That's right. Note that for the limit of the log, you don't really need  L'Hospital's rule, as the fraction is just a rate of variation, so the limit is just the derivative of the log at $x=0$.