# Prove that $f'$ is continuous, knowing that it has lateral limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(x)-f'(x)$ is monotonic.
>   Prove that $f'$ is continuous

$f(x)-f'(x)$ is monotonic, so it has finite left/right-hand limits at any point. The same can be said about $f$, because it is continuous, so $f'$ has also finite left/right-hand limits at any point $a\in \mathbb{R}$, call them $l=\lim_{x\nearrow a}f'(x)$ and $r=\lim_{x \searrow a}f'(x).$ But $f'(a)=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, so $$f'(a)=\lim_{x \nearrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \nearrow a} f'(x)=l$$
and $$f'(a)=\lim_{x \searrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \searrow a} f'(x)=r$$
from l'Hospital rule. But this means that $f'(a)=l=r$, so $f'$ is continuous at $a$.

Is this proof ok?

Comment: How do the second equalities (in each line) come about?

Comment: Can't we apply l'Hospital rule? The numerator and denominator both go to $0$, so I replaced them with their derivatives, knowing that the latter limits exist.

Comment: I would just add that as an explanation. Otherwise, good. Nvm. I just saw that. My oversight. Sorry.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: No, your proof is not correct.

Comment: @ GhD Can you please point out which part is wrong?

Comment: @GhD The proof is good.

Comment: $\lim_{x \nearrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \nearrow a} f'(x)$ this is completely wrong.

Comment: By Darboux theorem derivatives can't have simple discontinuity. So if the lateral limits for $f'$ exist they must be equal to the value of $f'$ and thus it is continuous.

Comment: Your approach has a minor flaw. You need to write $\lim_{x\to a^{-}} f'(c_x)=l$ where $x<c_x<a$ via mean value theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But isn't it quite the same as what I did with l'Hospital? I just applied it for left/right-hand sides, and according to  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1523407 it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the mention of L'Hospital's Rule. It's not one of my favorite tools. But then your solution is correct /rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint:

We know that men value theorem is true for $f'$. Now use proof by contradiction and suppose $f'$ is not continuous. You should find use of continuity of $f$ and discontinuity of $f'$, then you will find $f(x)-f'(x)$ non-monotonic.